# jquery - reference value from one function in another

Tags: jquery, function

Have I missed something here?

I have a some html code:

```
<td class="clickable" data-type="connect1">ABC</td>
```

I then have the following jquery functions:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    showDetails();
}

getTypeToUse = function()
{
    dataType=$(this).data("type");
    console.log("dataType:"+dataType);
}

showDetails = function()
{
    $('body').on('click','.clickable',function()
    {
        getTypeToUse();
    })
}
```

But when I click on the `<td>` I get `dataType:undefined`.

If I put the code inside of `showDetails()` it works as expected and returns `dataType:connect1`.

But as I want the `getTypeToUse` function to be available elsewhere later on, I wanted to keep it separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` inside of your `getTypeToUse` refers to the `window` object, not the clicked element. You need to pass the element or the event to your function as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    showDetails();
});
    
getTypeToUse = function($ele) {
    dataType = $ele.data("type");
    console.log("dataType:"+dataType);
};
    
showDetails = function() {
    $('body').on('click','.clickable',function() { 
        getTypeToUse($(this));
    });
};
```